# Prove $(9^n-1)/8$ is never prime (always composite or $1)$

Tags: prime-numbers, natural-numbers

I want to prove that none of the numbers $1_{(9)},11_{(9)},111_{(9)},1111_{(9)}\cdots$ are prime where $x_{(9)}$ means, the number $x$ is in base $9$. My first attempt was to try mathematical induction. $V(0)$ works because $1$ is not a prime. But then i couldn't prove the induction step anyhow.
$$1+9+81+...+9^n \text{ is not prime}\Rightarrow 1+9+81+...+9^{n+1} \text{ is not prime}$$
My next try was to prove it with geometric series.
Let $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n9^n$$
We are proving $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}:s_n \text{ is not prime}$.
using the sum of geometric series$$s_n=\frac{9^n-1}{8}$$ But here  I am stuck again and have no idea how to show that this can't be prime for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Half of them are even numbers $>2$, so that already takes care of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
$$9^n-1=(3^n)^2-1=(3^n-1)(3^n+1)$$

Now, $3^n-1, 3^n+1$ are two consecutive even numbers, thus one is divisible by $4$ and the other by 2. Consider the two cases (when $4|3^n-1$ and $4|3^n+1$) and write $\frac{9^n-1}{8}$ as a product of two integers. Explain why neither can be 1.

Comment: Denote $a=3^n+1, b=3^n-1$ Two cases: $4|a, 4∤b$ and $4|b, 4∤a$. The denominator can be factored $8 = 4\cdot2$. So we have: $$\frac{9^n-1}{8}=\frac{a}{4}\cdot\frac{b}{2}$$ if $4|a$, else switch $a,b$. Then, both are equal to one only if $n=1$ and $1$ is not a prime. If atleast one of them is equal to one, then the second one is still an even number not equal to $2$ or $4$ therefore still divisible and not prime. Is that correct?

Comment: @MichalDvořák Note that for $n\geq 2$ you have $a \geq b \geq 8$ thus $\frac{a}{4} >1$ and $\frac{b}{4}>1$.. So as long as $n \geq 2$ both $\frac{a}{4}$ and $\frac{b}{2}$ are strictly greater than 1.